# *ngif - Hide div if something becomes visible

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

ngif is confusing me!

I want to hide an image which is there when the page is empty, but when it becomes populated I want to hide it. I don't really know how to do this without doing it on a button.

So I have

```
<ion-content padding>
    <template ngFor let-api [ngForOf]="shoppingList">
        <ion-card>
            <ion-card-header>
                {{api?.name}}
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-list inset>
                <ion-item *ngFor="let ingredient of api.ingredientLines">
                    <ion-label>{{ ingredient }}</ion-label>
                    <ion-checkbox item-right></ion-checkbox>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <button ion-button block full color="danger" (click)="clear(api)">Remove</button>
        </ion-card>
    </template>

    <div class="text">
        <img class="shopping-icon" src="assets/icon/shopping-list.svg">
        <p>This is your shopping list, add recipes and shop away!</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I want to say, when there is content in the template or ion-card to hide the text div at the bottom. If someone could help me out that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably as simple as `<div class="text" *ngIf="!shoppingList.length">`

If your `shoppingList` is empty it hasn't been populated by the API yet so the image will be shown and no `ion-card`s will be shown since there aren't any available.

You could also use a property in your controller:

```
loading = true;

/* snip */

this.shoppingList.push(item);
loading = false;
```

Then you can use `*ngIf=loading` and have more explicit control over when you show this input or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your content is stored in `shoppingList`, then you could do:

```
<img *ngIf="shoppingList.length" class="shopping-icon" src="assets/icon/shopping-list.svg">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
 <div class="text" *ngIf="shoppingList.length">
        <img class="shopping-icon" src="assets/icon/shopping-list.svg">
        <p>This is your shopping list, add recipes and shop away!</p>
    </div>
```